# Windows that start out maximized restore to an application-specific size, not always a good one

Tags: compiz, gtk, window-manager, qt

I don't know that this is an OS-specific thing, a bug in the various UI toolkits in use, or purely application-specific, but the inconsistency is mildly infuriating - enough, at least, to get me to formalize it as a bug.

My question, for all you system-savvy Vervet-wranglers is: to whom do I report these as potential bugs?  Alternately, are there configuration options I can twiddle to make things work as expected across the board?

General testing pattern:

- Run
- Set window size to reasonable size (ref: SZ)
- Close
- Run

  - Expectation 1: window size matches SZ
- Maximize
- Close

  - Expectation 2: window is maximized
- Unmaximize

  - Expectation 3: window size matches SZ

Reasonable exceptions:

- Application has explicitly configured default dimensions

Examples:

- Chrome:

  - Expectation 1: window size matches SZ [OK]
  - Expectation 2: window is maximized [OK]
  - Expectation 3: window size matches SZ [Fail]

    - Window size is about 64x64
- Geany, gedit:

  - Expectation 1: window size matches SZ [OK]
  - Expectation 2: window is maximized [OK]
  - Expectation 3: window size matches SZ [Fail]

    - Window size matches screen size
- Firefox, Nautilus:

  - Expectation 1: window size matches SZ [OK]
  - Expectation 2: window is maximized [OK]
  - Expectation 3: window size matches SZ [OK]
- gnome-terminal:

  - Application is excepted, as start window size is configurable

    - always starts at default size
    - doesn't preserve 'maximized' state